# Cannot make liquibase execute more than 1 script in one file

Tags: mysql, sqlite, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a spring-boot application and sqlite db.
If I write two scripts in one file, only first script make change to db. The table creates but no data inserts, though in log I see that both scripts were executed.
And if I write each script to separate file, then it is OK, table creates and data inserts.
How to make it execute more then one script in one single file?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acl_class
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
class    character varying UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO acl_class
(class)
VALUES
('models.User');
```

The same problem is with mysql db, but here my app falls with runtime error "Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;" But syntax is ok, and separately tables are creating without any problem:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acl_class
(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
class VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acl_sid
(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
principal    boolean  NOT NULL,
sid VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What does your master changelog look like? The likely issue is that you have not specified that Liquibase should split statements and what the split character should be. There is a recent blog post that covers this topic - https://www.liquibase.org/2020/01/plain-SQL.html

Comment: Thank U very much! I just added to the begining of my file with multiply scripts this two lines: 

--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset myname:create-multiple-tables splitStatements:true endDelimiter:; 

and and it worked!

P.S.
It is noteworthy, that I used to use before a file with several scripts using PostgreSql and there was no need to use this annotation. Therefore, I could not understand why it doesn't work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to SteveDonie the problem was solved easily: I just added to the begining of my file with multiply scripts this two lines:
  --liquibase formatted sql
  --changeset myname:create-multiple-tables splitStatements:true endDelimiter:;
and and it worked!